# Power shell cannot remove item

Tags: powershell

I currently hit the wall with this email script. The problem is the third line where I need to delete logs older than one day.

```
$Path = "D:\Log\delete_trace.log"
Write-Output "before delete"> $Path 
**(Get-ChildItem "D:\trace" -Recurse | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname) >> $Path  
(Get-ChildItem "D:\trace" -Recurse | 
  Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).addDays(-1)} |
    Remove-Item -Force) >> $Path**
Write-Output "preserved"  >> $Path
(Get-ChildItem "D:\trace" -Recurse | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname) >> $Path

$body =  Get-Content $Path |%{ "$_`n" }|Out-String

Send-MailMessage -from doNotReply@company.com -to "someone@company.com" -subject "Trace logs delete status"  -Body $body  -smtpServer smtp.company.com
```

So when I execute the third line I get this error:

*Remove-Item : Cannot remove item
D:\trace\509436.trc:
The process cannot access the file
'D:\trace\509436.trc'
because it is being used by another process.*

I'm aware that the problem is in the first file which is currently logging, but why is the script trying to delete the first file, although I put (Get-Date).addDays(-1) ?

How to bypass this ?

Thank you

Comment: You are making a call to the data - and while you do that, you want to remove it. Store the piped expression in an variable and remove it then.

Comment: Your primary problem is a logic error: to remove files OLDER than a day, use `-le`, not `-ge` - see [CFou's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64751842/45375).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will remove logs younger than one day

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\trace" -Recurse | 
  Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).addDays(-1)} |
    Remove-Item -Force
```

if you want to remove logs older than one day

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\trace" -Recurse | 
  Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).addDays(-1)} |
    Remove-Item -Force
```

However, @Adis1102 is right when he says  you will not have your delete log appended, Tee-Object cmdlet is useful for this :

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\trace" -Recurse | 
   Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).addDays(-1)} | Tee $Path -Append | 
     Remove-Item -Force
```

Answer (score 1):

[CFou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14463444/cfou) is correct about using `-lt` to get files **older** than the reference date.

Also, I would set that reference date to midnight using `(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date`

Your code uses `Get-ChildItem` three times, for every step of the way, but you could suffice with just one call.

Something like this:

```
$Path = "D:\Log\delete_trace.log"
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date   # set to midnight

# create the log file
Set-Content -Path $Path -Value "before delete"
$files = Get-ChildItem "D:\trace" -File -Recurse
# add all files found to the file
$files.Fullname | Add-Content -Path $Path  

# filter out files older than the reference date (-lt, not -ge)
$removed = @($files | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate})
if ($removed.Count) {
    # if you have any, remove these files and add their fullnames to the log
    Add-Content -Path $Path -Value "`r`ndeleted files"
    $removed.FullName | Add-Content -Path $Path  
    $removed | Remove-Item -Force
}

# filter out the complete file list to only keep the files that were not removed
$preserved = @($files.FullName | Where-Object { $removed.FullName -notcontains $_ })
if ($preserved.Count) {
    # if you have any, add their fullnames to the log
    Add-Content -Path $Path -Value "`r`npreserved files"
    $preserved | Add-Content $preserved
}

# send the email. Best thing is to build a Hashtable for all parameters and use that (called Splatting)
$mailParams = @{
    To         = 'someone@company.com' 
    From       = 'doNotReply@company.com'
    Subject    = 'Trace logs delete status'
    Body       = Get-Content -Path $Path -Raw
    SmtpServer = 'smtp.company.com'
    # maybe more parameters go here..
    # BodyAsHtml = $true
}
Send-MailMessage @mailParams
```

If you are sending the email as HTML with extra parameter `BodyAsHtml = $true`, you need to set the body to

```
Body = (Get-Content -Path $Path) -join '<br />'
```

<sup>1. [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) makes code better readable and maintainable on cmdlets that use a lot of parameters.
2. If you want the output on console screen aswell you can add switch `PassThru` to both the `Set-Content` and the `Add-Content` cmdlets.</sup>